# Combobox dinámico muestra Paises y Provincias pero no salen las Ciudades

Tags: php, javascript

Dispongo de un combobox para hacer el típico formulario donde eliges el país (por ejemplo España), y en el desplegable de provincia ya sólo tienes para elegir las provincias de españolas, y una vez elegido por ejemplo *Gipuzkoa* (como provincia), en el desplegable de ciudades te salen sólo ciudades de *Gipuzkoa* como pueden ser *Donostia* y *Irún* o *Hernani*.

**PAISES y PROVINCIAS funcionan, CIUDADES no sale nada en el desplegable.**

*Contenido: Base de datos de 3 tablas (países, provincias, ciudades), archivos de consulta paises.php, provincias.php y ciudades.php, y una función javascript para que se vean las `select` en el desplegable FUNCTION.JS*

**Creo que el error está en el FUNCTION.JS que me falta algo para que las ciudades también se visualicen. Paises y Provincias se ven perfectamente.**

Tengo en la base de datos 3 tablas:

- Paises
- Provincias
- Ciudades

(Se han creado las tablas con algunos ejemplo de países, provincias y ciudades)

**En el formulario HTML donde tendremos los desplegables de País, Provincia y Ciudad:**

```
    <div>
<h2>País</h2>
<select name="paises" id="paises">
  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Provincia</h2>
<select name="provincias" id="provincias">
  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Ciudad</h2>
<select name="ciudades" id="ciudades">
  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Después las consultas en varios archivos php: paises.php, provincias.php y ciudades.php:

**PAISES.PHP**

```
 <?php
include ('conexion.php');
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM paises");
echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';
while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() )
{
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id_pais']. '">' . $row['nombre_pais'] . '</option>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

**PROVINCIAS.PHP**

```
    <?php
include ('conexion.php');
$el_pais = $_POST['pais'];
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM provincias WHERE id_pais = $el_pais");
echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';
while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() )
{
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id_provincia']. '">' . $row['nombre_provincia'] . '</option>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

**CIUDADES.PHP**

```
    <?php

include ('conexion.php');
$la_provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ciudades WHERE id_provincia = $la_provincia");
echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';
while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() )
{
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id_ciudad']. '">' . $row['nombre_ciudad'] . '</option>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

Y por último la función de llamada donde **creo que está el error o falta algo para que las ciudades aparezcan**:

**FUNCTION.JS**

```
$(function()
{

// Lista de Paises
$.post( 'paises.php' ).done( function(respuesta)
{
    $( '#paises' ).html( respuesta );
});

// lista de Provincias  
$('#paises').change(function()
    {
        var el_pais = $(this).val();

    // Lista de Paises
    $.post( 'provincias.php', { pais: el_pais} ).done( function( respuesta )
    {
            $( '#provincias' ).html( respuesta );
        });
    });

// Lista de Ciudades
$( '#provincias' ).change( function()
{
        var pais = $(this).children('option:selected').html();
    alert( 'Lista de Provincias de ' + provincia );
});

})
```

**¿Dónde está el error? ¿Qué falta?
Gracias de antemano.**

Comment: En ningún momento haces la petición a `CIUDADES.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregarle al `change()` de provincias la funcionalidad de buscar las ciudades te dejo mas o menos el ejemplo de como.

La idea es hacer la petición al hacer `change()` en provincias.

```
 $( '#provincias' ).change()
```

---

Luego pasarle como parametro al metodo `$.post()` el id de la provincia seleccionada que lo hacemos con

```
 { provincia: $( '#provincias' ).val()}
```

o también podría ser así

```
 { provincia: $(this).val()}
```

---

Y al final hay que obtener los valores que nos retorna la petición y agregarselos al `select` de ciudades

```
$( '#ciudades' ).html( respuesta );
```

---

```
$(function()
{

// Lista de Paises
$.post( 'paises.php' ).done( function(respuesta)
{
   $( '#paises' ).html( respuesta );
});

// lista de Provincias  
$('#paises').change(function()
{
    var el_pais = $(this).val();

// Lista de Paises
$.post( 'provincias.php', { pais: el_pais} ).done( function( respuesta )
{
        $( '#provincias' ).html( respuesta );
     });
});

// Lista de Ciudades
$( '#provincias' ).change( function()
{
    //var pais = $(this).children('option:selected').html();

    //Nuevo codigo
    // Lista de Ciudades
   $.post( 'ciudades.php', { provincia: $( '#provincias' ).val()} ).done( 
   function( respuesta )
    {
        $( '#ciudades' ).html( respuesta );
       alert( 'Lista de ciudades ' + respuesta);
     });

});

})
```

Espero te ayude amigo saludos.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. He quitado ese alert que sale, por lo demás funciona perfecto. Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Exelente amigo dale como respuesta correcta para que la comunidad sepa como solucionar el problema en caso de tenerlo saludos.